# How can I do this type of Array in Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, handlebars.js

I'm trying to recreate the following loop in Handlebars.

JAVASCRIPT VERSION - SAMPLE CODEPEN
https://codepen.io/Len/pen/PozvRrd

As you see, it creates every combination from 2 arrays. When I tried to convert the working JS code in handlebars as a helper, I get the error ..."Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined."

I tried to find a working version of this in handlebars, I've found some things but did not find the same generated results as the code pen.

My questions are below....

1 - What kind of loop is this called, when you iterate over each and every combination as you see in the output?

2 - Can someone point me to a sample of this being done in Handlebars?

Heres the code in Javascript that I'm trying to convert to Handlbars. I have oral surgery tmrw, sorry if I am slow getting back. Thanks in advance!

```
let arrayOne = [
  1,2,3,4,5
]

let arrayTwo = [
  "a","b","c","d","e"
]

arrayOne.forEach(printArrayOne);

function printArrayOne(item, index){  
  arrayTwo.forEach((value) => {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += item + ' - ' + value + "<br>";
  });
}

// OUTPUT
1 - a
1 - b
1 - c
1 - d
1 - e
2 - a
2 - b
2 - c
2 - d
2 - e
3 - a
3 - b
3 - c
3 - d
3 - e
4 - a
4 - b
4 - c
4 - d
4 - e
5 - a
5 - b
5 - c
5 - d
5 - e
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best way is to review approach and use computed data in handlebars template, but anyway, regarding to questions:

1 - It looks like a [nested loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_loop_join)

2 - Using existing data structures it's possible to loop in the same way as in JavaScript:

```html
{{#each arrayOne}}
   {{#each ../arrayTwo}}
      {{../this}} - {{this}}<br>
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Access to iteration variables within nested block described [here](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each), in last paragraph of `#each` helper description.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/rh86gst0/

Comment: Bro this worked! Thanks man I've been trying to work this out for days lol. Did not know about the ../ operator. It could be me but I wish their docs were a bit better. Thanks again!

Comment: So I went ahead and replaced the arrays with color hexes, arrayOne is text color and arrayTwo is div color. So this should spit out each text and bg combo so I can do a compliance test. The only issue is the first result is spitting out "[object Object] - #FFFFFF". Not sure why. I will try to fix but it you happen to know and feel like sharing I'm all ears. If not then no worries! Appreciate your help even this far.

Comment: Mb there is a typo somewhere, because here is same fiddle with hex colors: https://jsfiddle.net/jg7kbzp3/1/
And it's still better to review approach. Next example transforms data to suitable structure before passing it to view:
https://jsfiddle.net/k7a2bcvL/2/

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply I will check that and the fiddle. Thanks a lot!